# Powershell problem - i dont know how to make goto

Tags: powershell, goto, taskkill

i have an code and i want to do a goto but i dont know how to make it in Powershell

```
:yea
taskkill /im wordpad.exe /f
(get-process | ? {$_.Description -eq "Notepad"}).kill()
goto yea
```

i tried to read how to make it in google but i dont understeand anything xd
maybe its simple but i dont know how to make it

i read it something of

```
break and continue
```

please help me (:Yea and goto yea its when i want the loop)

aa
a

a
a

a
a

a
a
a

a
a
a
a

Comment: In the situtation you mentioned, you should use a while loop instead. Why do you want goto specifically?

Comment: and while loop for kill?

Comment: You can use continue or break with a label, but it's usually for nested loops https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_continue?view=powershell-7.1#using-a-labeled-continue-in-a-loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`while()` loop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_while):

```
while($true){
  taskkill /im wordpad.exe /f
  (get-process | ? {$_.Description -eq "Notepad"}).kill()
}
```